# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9 sonar (default-cli) on project x:Unable to determine structure of project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-shade-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

Env:

- Java : 8.0.392+8
- Sonar-Maven-plugin : 3.9.1.2184

we have a java project with about 7 pom files along with parent pom and 2 repos added as submodules and they also hold pom files and a total of 13 pom files.
the regular java build with maven successful without issue.

but while executing SonarQube analysis on Java project with maven build facing below error:

Sonarqube analysis on Java|

> Error: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project x: Unable to determine structure of project. Probably you use Maven Advanced Reactor Options with a broken tree of modules. "y" is orphan -> [Help 1]

java build and sonar scan runs on 2 different Ubuntu containers

got below article talks about same issue: https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/MSONAR-130
but i dont see maven-shade-plugin used in any of pom files in my project.

Am I missing anything?

Expected behavior: SonarQube analysis should be successfully done on java project and scan results need to be published to sonar dashboard.